# How to parse octet-stream files using Apache Tika?

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, apache-tika

I have stored all different types of files on Azure Blob storage, files are txt, doc, pdf,etc. However all the files are stored as 'octet-stream' there and when I open the files to extract the text from them using Tika, Tika cann't detect the character encoding. How can I get around this problem?

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());            
Path pt = new Path(Configs.BLOBSTORAGEPREFIX+fileAdd);          
InputStream stream = fs.open(pt);           


AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();   

parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);       


spaceContentBuffer.append(handler.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling Azure Storage REST API directly, you can set header "x-ms-blob-content-type" via API [Set Blob Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691966.aspx).

If you are using Azure Storage Client Library, you can write similar code as below:

```
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/xml";
blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

Comment: I'm using Azure Storage Client. I edit'ed my post so you can see my code. Could you provide me with more explanation considering my code?