# How come Tika parses plain text as octet/stream

Tags: apache-tika

Beside other files, I have tons of files for which the UNIX `file` command says: "ASCII text", but Tika insists that it is "application/octet-stream" and does not parse it. I naively use

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String text = tika.parseToString(inStream)
```

Some answers to [somehow related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011257/how-to-parse-octet-stream-files-using-apache-tika) point to the `AutoDetectParser`, but the default setup in version 1.13 uses exactly that.

Is there way to help Tika along such that it is more courageous in deciding for "text/plain" if there is a lot of ascii in the file?

Comment: Give Tika the file rather than an input stream, so  it knows the filename?

Comment: How can a file name like "blafasel" help? It does in particular not have a suffix.